# How to give two css class name together ,second one is removed after page is rendered?

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

```
var cssClass ;
cssClass = "fa-leaf green-icon";
var textValue = '<span  class=' + cssClass + '>' + nodeName + '</span>';
```

later I've used this text value to in column header in grid panel in Extjs 6.

When page is played green-icon class is removed  from class, it becomes like this

`<span class="fa-leaf" green-icon>name</span>, but it should have been like` this:

```
 <span class="fa-leaf green-icon">name</span>
```

Comment: It would be better if you can post a working [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) to describe your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code suggest that you start off with `'<span  class=fa-leaf green-icon>name</span>`, since you do not include the `"` quotes when creating the html string.

Try that first. When constructing HTML with string concatenation, you have to write the quotes around attributes yourself.
The browser can interpret attributes not wrapped between `"`, but as you see that leads to issues when the value contains spaces, since `<span class="fa-leaf" green-icon>` basically means the span has a class attribute with the value fa-leaf and a green-icon attribute without a value that the browser will ignore.

So try: `var textValue = '<span  class="' + cssClass + '">' + nodeName + '</span>';` first and see how extjs reacts to it.